# Two SSDs + one HDD, Where should I install Windows, Users folder (including AppData and Temp folder), my programs and games in terms of performance?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, performance, gaming

i have two SSDs (128GB NVMe M.2 + 128GB SATA SSD) and a 1TB HDD. each of them has one partition.
my purpose is gaming and then using some programs like Photoshop CS6. where i should install Windows in term of gaming performance? i think if i install Windows as well as my important games on the NVME M.2 SSD, it might affect the performance of my games since the OS also uses this SSD. i guess installing games and OS on different SSD would be better( OS on SATA SSD and important games on fastest SSD), if im wrong correct me please. on the other hand, i heard that some important files and dlls used in games (like DirectX and .NET framework) are in Windows folders like System32, so maybe installing OS on second SSD (SATA) is even worse?

also my important programs are about 5GB (many of them are portable) and rarely used programs and other data are 70GB and my common user folders (like Downloads, Videos, Music, Pictures) are 80GB.

i know i can easily move common user folders with Properties -> Location tab, but how about AppData? yesterday i read an article that said it is possible to [move whole **Users** folder during Windows installation](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html). are you recommend it? where should i move it? i think its good idea to move AppData to same SSD that i moving the important programs to, right? (i guess if their data is near them, they can access it faster)

im completely confused and cant test these many things myself because its too time consuming and requires technical knowledge.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but your SSDs are very small, almost too small. A single game could fill an entire SSD completely. Windows needs a lot of breathing room, too.

Comment: yeah i can install two big games on two ssd. also i will install Atlas OS, it only consumes about 10GB. so if my game is 90GB windows has about 20GB for breathing.